# Drools Execution Order

Tags: drools, execution, rule-engine

I am facing a problem of drools execution order changed after upgrading from drools-5.0.1 to drools-5.3.1. I have more than ten thousand rules in my decision table.

Drools-5.0.1 is using LIFO (bottom-up) approach to execute rules.
Drools-5.3.1 is using FIFO (Top - Down) approach to execute rules.

I also have salience in place and I understand that FIFO/LIFO approach takes precedence.

ISSUE : Is there anyway in drools-5.3.0 that I can configure LIFO/FIFO (as required) conflict resolution strategy.

I know that depending on execution order is not recomended in Drools Rule Engine. But currently I need it.

Comment: If you wish to control execution order, then salience is the way to do it. This takes precedence over the order in which you have created your rules. As you are noticing, relying on the order in which you create rules does not work if you ever wish to change/upgrade the Drools version.

Comment: @Steve. Thanks for your reply. I need to add that I have salience in place but still whats happening is that I am getting a LIFO execution order.

Comment: I reckon you will need to provide an example of two rules which both have LHS which evaluates to true and where the rule with the lower salience is activating before/instead of the higher salience rule.

Comment: OP is talking about a decision table! It should be fairly easy to change the evaluation order by hacking the decision table compiler of 5.3.x. But I think that salience must be stronger than any order in a decision table. Possibly the order matters when lines have equal salience. - Is this an XLS decision table?!

Comment: ... but every row in a decision table compiles to a rule. Hence the request: Show me 2 rules (or even just table rows) with different salience where the order in which they were created overrides their salience. A web decision table would even offer the "view source" option to see the rules, but I'm assuming it must be an XLS decision table due to the number of rows. Web decision tables are flaky above a couple of hundred rows.

Comment: Yes its a XLS decision table